# XAMPP with Apache; .htpassword passwords dont get read as encrypted

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

When trying to password protect a page using .htaccess and .htpasswd, I go to the page I have protected and type in the username and password. The problem is the password I encrypted is not the one I have to type in. Instead it is the encrypted password.

For Example:

```
lol:noitcS2m.5F6.
```

I enter `lol` as the username and `noitcS2m.5F6.` as the password and it lets me in.

However, if I use the password I encrypted it doesn't work. Could anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? I installed XAMPP 1.8.0, with Apache 2.4.2 and PHP 5.4.4.

My .htaccess file includes the following :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile C:/xampp/htdocs/pass/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

It is located in `C:/xampp/htdocs/dl/`

Also if I the `AuthUserFile` is `/dl/.htpasswd` then it will give me error 500.

Comment: Can you also provide .htaccess ? thanks

Comment: Ok I updated the post with what is in the .htaccess file. And also when I try username and password as above and then go to an .mp3 file it wont load it

Comment: I suggest you to run the following code ([link](http://pastebin.com/G578p8bC)), it will encrypt your password correctly. Then you put it into your passwd: lol:<your pass>. And don't forget to type a newline at the end of your file.

Comment: I got the password and replaced the orginal one. Yet I type `test` as the password and `lol` as the username but its still not accepting it and only the encrypted one as the password. Also in my browser it says `your password will be sent unencrypted` if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**In case anyone might need direction** *(FOR APACHE 2.2 and GREATER/Current XAMPP)*

Go to your **default XAMPP folder** then go to **apache/bin/error.log**. This file contains all errors that occur on Apache files within localhost - it makes things much easier to diagnose.

Example (one of mine):

```
[auth_basic:error] [pid 408:tid 1772] [client 127.0.0.1:4077] AH01617: user go_admin: authentication failure for "/HTAccessible/test/London/": Password Mismatch, referer: http://localhost/HTAccessible/test/London/
```

Run the directory again and then scroll to the bottom of the file for the error message that shows so StackOverflow can help you better.

---

**Possible Solution**

Also [Alain Tiemblo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/731138/alain-tiemblo). I have recently also had problems with the crypt(base64()) encryption method on Windows XAMPP - having looked at the Apache site it is suggested this method also.

```
'{SHA}' . base64_encode(sha1($password, TRUE)); //which works
```

Alternatively you can Open the Command Prompt (Start Menu->Accessories-> Command Prompt) and do these methods (since you are using Apache directly it should always encrypt correctly):

[The method described here works for htpasswd](http://www.stabeler.com/blog/487/)